# Android Development Switch case problems

Tags: java, android, mobile, switch-statement, case

```
            package com.gofitness.www;

            import android.app.Activity;


            import android.os.Bundle
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TextView;


            public class log extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button submit,bEdit, bGetInfo, bDelete;
    TextView display;
    EditText etRowInfo, username, password;




    protected void onCreate(Bundle login) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(login);
    setContentView(R.layout.insert);

     submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
  display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
 bEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
 etRowInfo  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRowInfo);
 bGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGetInfo);
 bDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);

  submit.setOnClickListener(this);
  etRowInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    switch (arg0.getId()){
                    case R.id.submit:
                            display.setText("fdf");
                    boolean didItWork = true;

                    try{
                    String check = username.getText().toString();
                    String checkpass = password.getText().toString();

                    logindetails entry = new logindetails(log.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(check, checkpass);
                    entry.close();


                    }catch (Exception e){
                    didItWork = false;
                    String error = e.toString();
                    display.setText(error);
                    }finally{
                    if (didItWork){

                    display.setText("WERKED");
                    }
                    }





                    break; 
                    case R.id.bGetInfo:
                            display.setText("fdf");
                            String s = etRowInfo.getText().toString();
                            long l = Long.parseLong(s);
                            logindetails log = new logindetails(this);
                            log.open();
                            String returnedName = log.getName(l);
                            String returnedPassword = log.getPassword(l);
                            log.close();

                            password.setText(returnedPassword);

                            break;


                    case R.id.bEdit:
                            display.setText("fdf");


                            break;



                    case R.id.bDelete:
                            display.setText("fdf");


                            break;



            }





    }
    }
```

It seems the first case works and the button changed the display Text View, however the rest of the buttons do not work. Upon clicking nothing happen but no errors either.

Anyone know why this happens?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You  did not set  onClickListeners on all your buttons.

Only on these two:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(this);
etRowInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Add these:

```
bEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
bDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
bGetInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to write @override before your onClick method as it is interface so we need to write it or take help from the code below

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button b1,b2;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

                b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                b1.setOnClickListener(this);
                b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            }



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 int id=v.getId();
                 switch(id) {
                    case R.id.button1:
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "btn1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Your Operation

                  break;

                    case R.id.button2:
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "btn2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                          //Your Operation
                          break;
            }

        }}
```